# jquery datepicker auto advance end date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker and would like the `end date` to auto advance by 1 day from the `start date`

I have got the following code so far and it's almost working, just not adding the +1 to the date:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker-8" ).datepicker({
        prevText:"click for previous months",
        nextText:"click for next months",
        showOtherMonths:true,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#datepicker-9" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#datepicker-9").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#datepicker-9").datepicker("setDate", "+1d");
        }
    });
    $( "#datepicker-9" ).datepicker({
        prevText:"click for previous months",
        nextText:"click for next months",
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#datepicker-8" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

This has been a combination of info found here and elsewhere, but I just cant seem to complete it. I also require the `minDate` and `maxDate` features to remain, but these are working well.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$( "#datepicker-8" ).datepicker({
  prevText:"click for previous months",
  nextText:"click for next months",
  showOtherMonths:true,
  selectOtherMonths: false,
  dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
  onClose: function( selectedDate,inst ) {
    console.log(selectedDate);
    var parts = selectedDate.split('-');
    var mydate = new Date(parts[2], (parts[1] - 1), parts[0]);
    console.log( "my date:"+ mydate );
    mydate.setDate(mydate.getDate() + 1);
    $( "#datepicker-9" ).datepicker( "setDate", mydate );
  }
});

$( "#datepicker-9" ).datepicker({
  prevText:"click for previous months",
  nextText:"click for next months",
  defaultDate: "+1d",
  dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#datepicker-8" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
```

here is a working [fiddler](https://jsbin.com/meyowujiwe/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I had to combine it somewhat to acheive the minDate Maxdate filter, but this works well.

Comment: Great! Hope everything is good. Btw can you mark it as an answer/vote to close this?